# How to manage selected leaf given the use of the State plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, jstree

If I have a user open a tree, make a leaf selection, and close that page, then the next time the user opens the tree they are returned to the same node & leaf as when the pages was last closed.

In my case however, between closing and re-opening the tree my user's do other things in other application pages that can mean I want the tree to be re-opened with a different leaf selected (but same node).

How do I manually setting the selected leaf given that I'm using the 'state' plugin?

Thanks.

Comment: It means you either update the JSON in your local storage where state plugin saved the tree data or you select the node you want programatically at tree load.

Comment: Can you demo both/either option?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As long as you use a `state` plugin, every change you make will be immediately written to your localStorage.

To update it programmatically you would use this:

```
// get the object out of data in localStorage
var treeObj = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('jstree')); 

// update the selected items array
treeObj.state.core.selected = [ "yourNewId"]; 

// save it back
localStorage.setItem( 'jstree', JSON.stringify(treeObj) );
```

Check demo - [Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ermakovnikolay/c1jms0x0/).  There click `update` button and run fiddle again. You will see that the selected node now changed to `Cat 0.3`.

Comment: That's awesome!  THANKS

Answer (score 0):

About as simply of a jsTree example as you will ever find.
Many thanks to @Nikolay Ermakov

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jstree/3.2.1/themes/default/style.min.css" />
</head>
<body>


<div id="myTree">
</div>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jstree/3.2.1/jstree.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        var data = [
             { "id": "root", "parent": "#", "text": "Root" },
             { "id": "cat1", "parent": "root", "text": "First Branch" },
             { "id": "cat01", "parent": "cat1", "text": "Cat 0.1" },
             { "id": "myIDstring", "parent": "cat1", "text": "Cat 0.2" },
             { "id": "cat03", "parent": "cat1", "text": "Cat 0.3" },
             { "id": "cat011", "parent": "cat01", "text": "Cat 0.1.1" },
             { "id": "cat012", "parent": "cat01", "text": "Cat 0.1.2" },
             { "id": "cat013", "parent": "cat01", "text": "Cat 0.1.3" }
        ]



        $('#myTree').jstree({ core: { data: data } })
       .on('ready.jstree', function () {
            $('#myTree').jstree("open_all");
            var t = $('#myTree').jstree(true);
            var n = t.get_node("myIDstring");
            console.log(n.id, n);
            n = t.get_node("cat012");
            console.log(n.id, n);
            t.select_node(n);
            n = t.get_selected(true);
            console.log(n[0].id, n[0]);
        });
    });
</script>
</body>
</html>
```